# Anaconda Acclerate / NumbaPro CUDA Linking Error OSX

Tags: python, gpu, jit, anaconda, numba-pro

Overall goal is to use [NumbaPro](http://docs.continuum.io/numbapro/index.html) to run some functions on the GPU (on OSX 10.8.3).

Before starting, I just wanted to get everything set up. According to [this page](http://docs.continuum.io/numbapro/CUDASupport.html) I installed CUDA, registered as a CUDA developer, downloaded the Compiler SDK and set up the NUMBAPRO_NVVM=/path/to/libnvvm.dylib environment variable.

However, running this basic test function:

```
from numbapro import autojit

@autojit(target='gpu')
def my_function(x):
    if x == 0.0:
        return 1.0
    else:
        return x*x*x

print my_function(4.4)
exit()
```

Brings up this error:

```
File ".../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/decorators.py", line 207, in compile_function
    compiled_function = dec(f)
File "...lib/python2.7/site-packages/numbapro/cudapipeline/decorators.py", line 35, in _jit_decorator
File "...lib/python2.7/site-packages/numbapro/cudapipeline/decorators.py", line 128, in __init__
File "...lib/python2.7/site-packages/numbapro/cudapipeline/environment.py", line 31, in generate_ptx
File "...lib/python2.7/site-packages/numbapro/cudapipeline/environment.py", line 186, in _link_llvm_math_intrinsics
KeyError: 1
```

I've tried @vectorize'ing instead of autojit, same error. 
@autojit by itself with no target works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: You may also want to ask the NumbaPro people.  I note on the site you linked it states: "GPU support is rapidly improving but still an area where you may encounter difficulties. Please let us know if you have any trouble with our GPU support."  As a product that expects you to [pay for it's use after 30 days](http://docs.continuum.io/numbapro/eula_numbapro.html#trial-period), I would assume they would offer support of some sort.

Comment: This really isn't a CUDA question. I am tempted to remove the CUDA tag altogether....

Comment: @RobertCrovella, I'm aware NumbaPro is a paid product, I'm using the [academic license.](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/academicanaconda) I'll try emailing them, but I was hoping for a quick-and-easy fix.

Comment: @talonmies, You're right. Done.

Answer (score 5):

For posterity's sake, I asked Continuum Support. They responded:

> It seems that you are running a CUDA GPU with compute capability 1.x. NVVM only supports CC2.0 and above. We definitely should have a better error reporting and make it clear in the NumbaPro documentation for the supported compute capability.